# JavaFX Login screen

Tags: authentication, javafx-2

I am trying to make an application with a login screen. All the examples I have found talk about making the screen itself, but not how it fits in with the larger picture (application).

So I have made my login screen, which verifies the user in an SQL database. The login screen works perfectly, but from there I need it to launch the application itself and track the logged-in user, which I think should be easily done, as the database identifies each user with a unique Key. The question here is, how do I launch my application with the user Key as a parameter that will persist through the different screens they can open from the main application?

Currently I'm launching the login screen first, from which once the user is verified a new Stage is created for the main application. The relevant code (once the user is verified) is:

```
/*
 * login is correct
 */                                
Node source;
source = (Node) t.getSource();
Stage thestage = (Stage) source.getScene().getWindow();
thestage.close();
Stage homestage = new Stage();
AnchorPane home = (AnchorPane) FXMLLoader.load(Punto_de_Venta.class.getResource("PuntoDeVenta.fxml"));
Scene homescene = new Scene(home);
homestage.setScene(homescene);
homestage.setTitle("LanzDom Punto de Venta");
homestage.show();
```

I had originally thought about opening the main application first without showing the stage, and nesting in the login screen. The idea was that I could set a variable in the home screen, update it in the login screen with the user's Key, which would be returned when the user was verified. However, a) I don't know what is the preferred method (or if there is one better than the two I've presented here) and b) the way I was doing it, if the user closes the login screen rather than clicking the "ok" button, the main application stage appears despite the user not being verified.

Any and all help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have an FXML called RootViewController that is put in the stage.  Here I put the login FXML control and then swap that out with the normal application window, although creating a new stage might be better.  The [login controller](https://bitbucket.org/atill/estimate/src/22390a2ca034b55f1916e46435b714e5c489b90e/src/main/java/projmon/control/LoginController.java?at=master) decides when to swap to the application.

Data in the application can be passed around by sharing objects between controllers, either by instantiating the controller yourself:

```
MyController controller = new MyController(sharedObject);
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
loader.setController(controller);
loader.load(getClass().getResource("/control.fxml");
```

Or you can use dependency injection.  Check out the full source at https://bitbucket.org/atill/estimate

Comment: Thank you. This worked for the most part. However, when I inject variables into a controller with a separate .fxml, if my variables are important BEFORE initialization, for some reason it would not work. As a workaround, in such cases I would roll my controller and GUI elements into a single .java file, which gave me better control over each element. I assume there must be a way to have variables established before GUI initialization, so that my variables can be used to activate/deactivate/hide different elements. Can anyone help with that?

Comment: In java, the constructor is always run before any methods can be called.  Just setup your variables there and then use them in the call to #initialize.